# Duplicated SPARQL subquery

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

In order to get the cartesian product of the results of a subquery, I duplicated the query and bound the result to different variables. But the inner queries are quite long, and exactly the same except for the `SELECT` line. Is there a way to simplify this?

I added a simplified version of my query below. What I'm actually trying to do is to find timetable conflicts in a set of events. The events are selected by the subqueries.

```
SELECT ?a1 ?b1 ?a2 ?b2
WHERE {

  SELECT (?a AS ?a1) (?b AS ?b1)
  WHERE {
    # long query with ?a and ?b
  }

  SELECT (?a AS ?a2) (?b AS ?b2)
  WHERE {
    # long query with ?a and ?b
  }

  FILTER (?a1 < ?a2)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual query with ?a and ?b.  I've posted an answer that may or may not help in your particular case, but knowing what the particular query is would help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the actual query. Thanks for the suggestions in your answer though!

Comment: OK, can you provide a similar query?  If you can show enough, it may be possible to show how it can be rewritten.

Comment: Thanks, but it's fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a query, and getting the results (twice):

```
{ < x1, y1>, < x2, y2 >, < x3, y3 >, ... }
{ < x1, y1>, < x2, y2 >, < x3, y3 >, ... }
```

You then want to filter so only those pairs of results where the first value in the first set is less the first of the second.

Now the number of results are going to increase fast, O(N^2). And you really don't need to bother with that anyway. Suppose (without loss of generality) you order the results by the first value, ascending. Then your first lot of results (indicated by `*`) are:

```
{ *< x1, y1>*, < x2, y2 >,    < x3, y3 >, ... }
{ < x1, y1>,   *< x2, y2 >*, *< x3, y3 >*, ... and everything else ... }
```

the second:

```
{ < x1, y1>, *< x2, y2 >*,    < x3, y3 >, ... }
{ < x1, y1>, < x2, y2 >, *< x3, y3 >*, ... and everything else ... }
```

etc etc

So you're much better off space wise, and probably time wise, just issuing the query:

```
SELECT ?a ?b
WHERE {
    # long query with ?a and ?b
}
ORDER BY ?a # defaults to ASCending
```

putting it in an array or similar, and looping through fetching items `results[i], results[j] where i > j`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea and probably the best way in practice. Do you know if any SPARQL engines are able to perform an optimization like you described?

Comment: No idea, but (pure guess) it would seem unlikely because it would need to spot that the subqueries are identical (somewhat tricky), and I imagine cases where that helps are fairly unusual. What you really need is a way to make it more explicit to the query engine that the subquery is reused, for example temporary tables or perhaps an explicit self cross join? Either way this is outside standard SPARQL.

Answer (score 1):

[user205512's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26927786/1281433) is up the right alley, I think.  I don't think that there's an easy way to get the cartesian product of an arbitrary query.  There is an advantage to having the server do it, and that is that it might be possible to stream the results, avoiding large amounts of intermediate storage, which is what you might need if you simply accept the results and compute the cartesian product yourself.

What I would point out, though, is that it might not be too difficult, depending on your particular query, to rewrite it in such a way that it computes the cartesian product for you.  This depends on the particular query, but the idea is that you could use the object list notation and move the variables into object position by using property paths.  For instance, consider a query like:

```
?a :p/:q ?b
```

You can exploit the fact that this matches data of the form

> X →<sub>p</sub> Y →<sub>q</sub> Z

to rewrite the query as:

```
[] ^:p ?a ; :q ?b
```

Now you can match two sets of ?a and ?b by using comma separated object lists:

```
[] ^:p ?a1, ?a2 ; :q ?b1, ?b2
```

You can't use that for *every* query of course, and you might still have to duplicate some parts, e.g., filter expressions, but it may be a viable alternative.